# Best way to deal with duplicate statuses using enums and models

Tags: php, laravel, enums

This question is related to formatting, presentation and autocompletion in regard to statuses. I haven't found a way to use enums efficiently for more complex scenarios.

I have multiple tables

- User
- Post
- Category

Every table has a `status` column as well as other enum columns. I have created the following enums:

- App\Enums\User\Status.php;
- App\Enums\Post\Status.php;
- App\Enums\Category\Status.php;

Inside of my code I need to refer to the statuses of every Model, such as:

```php
$user->status = Status::APPROVED;
$post->status = Status::COMPLETE;
$category->status = Status::OPEN;
```

The statuses dont relate to each other and are all different for every model. The issue is related to formatting, since its very easy to confuse the statuses if they all have the same prefix.

I know I can also do this:

```php
$user->status = \App\Enums\User\Status::APPROVED;
$post->status = \App\Enums\Post\Status::COMPLETE;
$category->status = \App\Enums\Category\Status::OPEN;
```

However that is not very clean and I wonder if there is any better way. Ideally I would like to do:

```php
$user->status = User::Status::APPROVED;
$post->status = Post::Status::COMPLETE;
$category->status = Category::Status:OPEN;
```

I tried doing this in my model, but does not work since I cant instantiate a new object outside of a method:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public Status $STATUS = new Status();
```

The above gives me autocomplete and a clean syntax but it does not work obviously.

Are there any solutions for my use case? Something that gives me auto-completion and keeps code clean and short?

Comment: you can add them to a config

Comment: I would like to use enums if possible, for type checking

Comment: or you can change name  same as :
`\App\Enums\User\Status as UserStatus;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use

```
class User extends Model
{
    /** @var Status */
    public static $status = Status::class;
}
```

Or

```
use \App\Enums\User\Status as UserStatus
```

Comment: The problem with this is some models have long names, and its also not obvious. A model such as UserPurchaseHistory, would them turn out to be UserPurchaseHistoryStatus, that is not obvious as well. I tried the Status::class, but it does not work since that resolves to a string and not to the Enum instance.

Comment: It resolves to the Enum instance, you can try User::$status::APPROVED, it works.@BernardWiesner